# byte[] receiverByte = new byte[BUFFER];

Tags: java, c

I need some help with the following line of code. I am writing my code in C and I need some replacement for following line of code in Java.
So please help me and suggest some alternatives on how I can  modify it for my C code. I am waiting for line of code.
Thanks..

```
byte[] receiverByte = new byte[BUFFER];
```

Comment: Do you really want `C` and not `C++`?

Comment: So, uh, you want Java code as answer, then? Seems most answers get this wrong.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] receiverByte = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE ];
```

becomes this if using a C++ compiler:

```
char* receiverByte = new char[BUFFER_SIZE ];
```

else in C:

```
char* receiverByte = malloc( BUFFER_SIZE );
```

Remember though that C is not memory managed like Java so you will need to call delete to free the memory when you are done:

So for C++:

```
delete[] receiverByte;
```

And for C:

```
free( receiverByte );
```

Also you could create a fixed size array on the stack. The size BUFFER_SIZE must be specified at compile time and the vector size cannot change or grow:

```
char receiverByte[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

EDIT: If you are using a c++ compiler you also have access to the STL library which removes the need to directly use new[] and delete[]:

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<char> receiverByte;
receiverByte.resize( BUFFER_SIZE );
```

Comment: This will not work if 'BUFFFER_SIZE' is not a constant value, which for `C` will require a macro. For C++ you should not use new and free, simple use a std::vector or std::aray

Comment: My comment was based on a previous version of this answer, and has since been rendered moot

Answer (score 2):

If `BUFFER` is defined as a macro:

```
#define BUFFER 1234
unsigned char receiveBuffer[BUFFER];
```

or using a dynamic allocation with [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
unsigned char *receiveBuffer = malloc(BUFFER);
```

As mentioned by @mic_e you should multiply `BUFFER` with the size of a `unsigned char` to be more platform independent, the second example becomes:

```
unsigned char *receiveBuffer = malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

the same goes for the first example.

Comment: You should not typecast the return of the allocation (or the argument to the `free`) functions.

Comment: You don't need to cast from malloc!

Comment: static double[][] sat_data = new double[19][4];
 static double[][] sat_data_notused = new double[19][4];
 static double[][] sbas_data = new double[4][2]; also i need the conversion of following line from java to c

Comment: However, in my opinion you should multiply by sizeof(unsigned char) in the malloc argument.

Comment: @user1954391 Please update you question... Your code snippet is unreadable in the comment (and it does not belong there)

Comment: In Java, "the byte data type is an 8-bit signed two's complement integer." So instead of using an `unsigned char`, you should use a `signed char` (the `signed` is necessary, because the C spec allows `char`s to be unsigned or signed unless specified).

Comment: The * sizeof(unsigned char) is not necessary. The OP was allocating BUFFER bytes of data. If the platform defined char as 16bits then you would be allocating twice as much memory as intended.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char receiverByte[BUFFER];
```

or

```
unsigned char* receiverByte = malloc(BUFFER);
if (!receiverByte ) my_do_with_error(....);
```

And:

```
double data[19][4];
```

But a dynamic array here will be more tricky (test for NULL)

```
int M= 19, N= 4;
double **data   =malloc(sizeof( *data)*M);
         data[0]=malloc(sizeof(**data)*M*N);
for(int i=1; i<M; ++i) data[i] =data[0]+i*N;
```

.....

```
free(data[0]);
free(data);
```

EDIT: [In 6.5.3.4 of the C standard we can find](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444):

```
#include <stddef.h>
size_t fsize3(int n)
{
  char b[n+3];     // variable length array
  return sizeof b; // execution time sizeof
}
int main()
{
  size_t size;
  size = fsize3(10); // fsize3 returns 13
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Should also add the first case will not work if BUFFER is not a compile time constant. If the size is fixed and known at compile time this is the way you should go.

Comment: @Crog : you may be surprised. See EDIT

Comment: You are very correct and I do recall something of that but overlooked it. Me being a Visual Studio user we don't get all/any of the C99 standard support :(

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `unsigned char*` as it resembles a byte in C. So it will be:

```
unsigned char* receiverByte = malloc(BUFFER * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

or

```
unsigned char receiverByte[BUFFER];
```